# opencv VideoCapture is blocked in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I need some some help with the usage of opencv VideoCapture in another thread.

When I use the [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) in the main thread, it is perfectly fine and it shows the video smoothly. But once I put the code in another thread and expect it do the same thing, it seems the VideoCapture does not work at all.

I made some attempts: if I initialize the VideoCapture with 0 (the default one) as parameter, it gets blocked. But if I don't initialize it

```
VideoCapture cap;
```

or use another number

```
VideoCapture cap(1);
```

it prints out error message and exits but does not get blocked.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

class MyClass {
public:
    // display the video
    static void display(int i) {
        VideoCapture cap(0);

        if (!cap.isOpened()) {
            cout << "cannot access webcame" << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }

        Mat imgOriginal;
        namedWindow("Original", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        while (true) {
            bool success = cap.read(imgOriginal);
            if (!success) {
                cout << "fail to read video into mat" << endl;
                break;
            }
            imshow("Original", imgOriginal);

            if (waitKey(30) == 27) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    //cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    thread myThread(bind(MyClass::display, 0));
    myThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Very appreciated if anyone can point out where I got it wrong. Thank you.

Comment: the highgui module is quite primitive, don't try to bend it. if you *have* to use threads, outsource you *processing task* to another thread, keep the capture and the gui in the main thread.

Comment: @berak thanks for the comment.. if it really does not work, I shall keep them in the main thread..